# failing to generate pact with specification v3 with pact-js

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pact

I'm currently working on a node.js project and trying to setup pact testing with the pact specification v3
While on the official documentation https://docs.pact.io/feature_support it seems that pact.js is not supporting v3 features, on the pact.js github they say they released an alpha that supports it
so i did change my dependencies accordingly

```
"devDependencies": {
"@pact-foundation/pact": "^10.0.0-beta.13",
"@pact-foundation/pact-node": "^10.9.6",
"jest": "^26.1.0",
"jest-pact": "^0.6.0",
"ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
"ts-node": "^8.10.2"
```

but when running my test script i get the following error

```
The specified module could not be found.
...\node_modules\@pact-foundation\pact\native\index.node
```

am i missing something?

also I use jest-pact to write my test file, can it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please raise an issue on the repo? It's not been tested to work with jest pact yet and it's likely incompatible

Comment: should i raise the issue on the pact-js repo or jest-pact repo?

Comment: The Pact JS repository please